# Can i mock file.mkdirs() which is inside of a method

Tags: java, file, junit, mocking

Here is my legacy code below. I don't want to create an actual folder. Instead I want to create a temp folder, which has to be deleted after test execution is over.

```
Public class MainClass() {
  public void m1() {
        m2();
  }

  private void m2() {
    File f=new File();
    f.mkrdirs()
  }
}
```

Here is my TestClass

```
public class TestClass{
       @Rule
       public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

       public void testM1(){
            File fileSpy = mock(File.class);
            Mockito.doNothing().when(fileSpy.mkdir());

       }
}
```

but not working.Any clues?

Comment: So you want to run test without creating directory (folder)?

Comment: @PareshLomate yes

Answer (score 4):

Your problem starts here:

```
File f=new File();
```

Your production code calls **new** for the file class.
In your test code, you do:

```
File fileSpy = mock(File.class);
```

And how is that spy related to your `f` instance? Answer: not at all.

Declaring a spy in your test doesn't magically make your production code use it! So you have to make sure that when your production code uses that `f` object ... `f` should be your `fileSpy`

Now you have these options:

- see if you can change your production code, so that you can *somehow* pass in a file instance. Either by making it an argument, that you really can pass something to, or by turning `f` into a field of your class, to then use Mockito's @InjectMock annotation
- if you are stuck with your production code, Mockito won't do. Then you need PowerMock(ito) or JMockit.

Typically, I advise people to stick with plain Mockito, and avoid mocking new() (even more so mocking *static* calls) via PowerMock(ito) like the plague.

But testing legacy code is the one situation where you have to choose between "not testing at all" or "testing with PowerMock(ito)". So, if you can't change your production code, then your only choice would be to mock that call to new(). See [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor) for how to do that.